# python beginner - repeating value of a list for a couple of times

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Trying to print the value in y for the number of times that shows in x.

How should I modify the following syntax to achieve the expected output?

```
x = 5
y = ['a', 'b']
z = []

for num in list(range(x)):
    for idx, num1 in enumerate(y):
        z.append(num1)
```

Output based on above:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Expected output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need the list() on range, it's already iterable. Also, you're not using the index, so don't bother with enumerate.

The problem is that you are repeating 5 times going through y and appending it z list. You need to do the opposite:

```
for num1 in y:
    for num in range(x):
        z.append(num1)
```

I also suggest to try a development environment that allows you to debug your program. Use it to get step by step into your code and understand exactly what the computer is doing when executing your code.

Comment: Thanks! may i know what development environment do you recommend?

Comment: It's a matter of taste, really. I'm using PyCharm (that has a free Community Edition) but it can be overwhelming and is pretty heavy. Spyder is popular with beginners and a lot of people like Visual Studio Code. All have good debugging features.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single pass.

```
z=[chr for chr in y for i in range(x)]
```